# Google Drive API - Getting list of revisions

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-apis-explorer

Using Python version of Google Drive API, when trying to list the revisions of a doc I get inconsistent results.

I keep getting inconsistent number of results. I have tried setting `pageSize` to smaller number and setting `nextPageToken` but still no luck. I have seen this issue with both version 2 and version 3. I also tried using Javascript web API calls but got the same results.

Has anyone else had this issue?

```
service.revisions().list(fileId=file_id, pageToken=page_token, fields='nextPageToken, items(modifiedDate, lastModifyingUserName, selfLink)').execute()
```

Even using the API explorer I get different results on subsequent calls to the same document. Perhaps this bug only appears with docs that have over a certain number of revisions?: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list

Comment: Someone else had the same issue but doesn't seem like it was ever resolved: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/725

Comment: Even just using the test interface: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list.  If I run the command on the same document multiple times I get different results. Perhaps this only happens with docs with a lot of revisions?(50+)

Comment: It seems to be related to the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70101398